# HTTP status 404 - /RESTfulWS/ While testing restful web service

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jersey

[Here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQBb.png)I am trying to develop the Restful Web-service but whenever I am trying to tun my application on server it shows :

HTTP status 404 - /RESTfulWS/
type Status report
message /RESTfulWS/
description The requested resource is not available.

My web.xml file contains :

display-name RESTful display-name

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.student</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Explain why `/RESTfulWS/` *should* work.

Comment: Is  "RESTfulWS" your war file name ? and also you configured url pattern as "rest\*" , you have not used in your url

Comment: No it's not my war file name. It's my project name
If I entered the URL : http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWS/rest/student,
it shows :  
HTTP status 404 - /RESTfulWS/rest/student 
type Status report 
message /RESTfulWS/ 
description The requested resource is not available.